# Moving columns in a bidemensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, alphabetical

Hello I have a bidimensional array initiated the following way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

char matriz[6][5]={
{'F','H','V','D','U'},
{'E','L','Q','U','E'},
{'P','E','R','S','E'},
{'V','E','R','A','A'},
{'L','C','A','N','Z'},
{'A','Z','Z','Z','Z'}};

system("pause");
}
```

And I need to move the columns, ordering alphabetically the first line,
I mean, the line that contains `{'F','H','V','D','U'}`.

I need the following output:

```
char matriz[6][5]={
{'D','F','H','U','V'},
{'U','E','L','E','Q'},
{'S','P','E','E','R'},
{'A','V','E','A','R'},
{'N','L','C','Z','A'},
{'Z','A','Z','Z','Z'}};
```

I know I need to use the selective ordering method and a cycle of fors, but I am not sure how.

Comment: What you are describing is not a transpose.

Comment: Is this an assignment? It sure does sound like it. Anyway, you can just [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) each array.

Comment: I'm not sure that a qsort will do it.  The elements are non-contiguous in memory.

Comment: @MartinJames Nope, `qsort` works. But the example output in the question is not correctly sorted.

Comment: @Leandros Entire column must be moved, while sorting the first element.

Comment: @Leandros exactly what 2501 said.

Comment: Shoot. Should've read the question better, I was sorting the rows alphabetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to **compare the first elements of each column** to all other top elements,if a column's **1st element is greater** than the next column's top element then **swap both columns**.You can also use **qsort** function in the **algorithm** header for sorting.

Below is the implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int i,k,j;        

    char matriz[6][5]={
    {'F','H','V','D','U'},
    {'E','L','Q','U','E'},
    {'P','E','R','S','E'},
    {'V','E','R','A','A'},
    {'L','C','A','N','Z'},
    {'A','Z','Z','Z','Z'}};

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(k=i+1;k<5;k++)
        {   
            //comparing top elements of columns 
            if(matriz[0][i]>matriz[0][k])
            {
                //swapping columns
                for(j=0;j<6;j++)
                {
                    int t=matriz[j][i];
                    matriz[j][i]=matriz[j][k];
                    matriz[j][k]=t;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //display

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<5;k++)
        printf("%c ",matriz[i][k]);
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Though the sorting algo is not too efficient but it will work for problem specified(as the matrix is short).

Answer (score 1):

Declare a struct:

```
typedef struct{
  colChar:char;
  colIndex:int;
} COL_HEADER;
```

Make an array of them, same length as row length:

COL_HEADER myColHeaders[5];

Load up each in a loop, colChar as the column header char, colIndex as the column index, 0-4.

Now you can qsort the array with a comparison function that just compares the colChar.  The colIndex keeps track of the initial columns.  You now know which col needs to go where in the output.

You can then use a couple of loops to copy the source columns to a 'dest' [6][5], using the myColHeaders[5].colIndex to identify the destination column for each source column.

Comment: This would be a better answer if the example were written in C rather than some kind of hybrid. But +1 anyway.

Comment: @rici I didn't want to do OP's homework in its entirety, so I gave a rough algorithm:)